# Central auth server with multiple clients using resource owner password credentials oauth flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've got the following set up:

- Central auth server written with spring boot that is currently working (I can curl and receive an access token, jdbc token store, etc)
- Multiple applications owned by the same developer, sharing the same customer base on different domains. IE: John Doe for app1 is the same as John Doe for app2.

I have an existing application (app1 above) that is jsf 2.2 with spring security configured for login purposes. That application works stand alone right now, with it's own user base.

This is the flow I am trying to obtain:
[Resource Owner Password Credential OAuth Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4wP.png)

So we would want:

1. User goes to app1
2. User enters user and password into app1 login page
3. User hits "login"
4. Some sort of configuration in Spring would then take the loginByUsername request, get access token from the central oauth server
5. We now have app1 access - the user could have one of three roles (ADMIN, USER, SUPERUSER).
6. When they go to (say) app1/views/createEntry.xhtml, we would confirm the access token we currently have is still active on the auth server.
7. The resource server would technically be the resources on the app1 server (right?)

I'm new to this oauth2.0 process (and spring really), but I think this is the flow I want. How do I set this up with Spring Security? I've seen a security setting called oauth2login() that I think is what we COULD want, but I think that is more authorization code flow.

I haven't found a very good example of this using the password flow.

I do trust each of the applications in this process, hence the password flow. We control the network that maintains traffic between the auth server and the other applications.

**Edit**: SSO isn't an option because of requirements and our customer base. The applications are unique enough that it doesn't make sense, but the user should be able to log into any of our applications with those credentials.

**Edit 2**: Sorry for second edit. I would like to add that I've added a resource configuration on app1 and it actually seems like it works - I've secured anything /views/* and when I attempt to go their, I get the expected "Full Authentication required" message.

**Edit 3**: I think I am making some progress -

First, I created a spring component that implements AuthenticationProvider and then overwrote the authenticate method so that I created a ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails object with all my properties (client id, client secret, grant type, scope, etc) and called the authorization server to get a token. My excitement to see my log refresh for the authorization server was high.

Next step I need to figure out is how to generate an extension of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User so that I can store the privileges for the user.

Also - I can't quite figure out yet how the token is stored. I know the auth server generates a token and stores in jdbc, but where/how does the token get stored on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that were curious, here is how I set up the authentication provider on my client (app1). I still have issues with the resource server (ill ask a separate question), but here is what I did:

Custom authenticator:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserDAO appUserDAO;

    private String accessTokenUri = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";
    private String clientId = "clientid";
    private String clientSecret = "clientsecret";

    public AccessTokenProvider userAccessTokenProvider() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
        return accessTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        final String username = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add("read");

        final ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

        resource.setUsername(username);
        resource.setPassword(password);
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setScope(scopes);

        // Generate an access token
        final OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));
        template.setAccessTokenProvider(userAccessTokenProvider());

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;

        try {
            accessToken = template.getAccessToken();
            System.out.println("Grabbed access token from " + accessTokenUri);
        }
        catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ResourceAccessException) {
                final String errorMessage = String.format(
                        "While authenticating user '%s': " + "Unable to access accessTokenUri '%s'.", username,
                        accessTokenUri);
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException(errorMessage, e);
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("Access denied for user '%s'.", username), e);
        }
        catch (OAuth2Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                    String.format("Unable to perform OAuth authentication for user '%s'.", username), e);
        }

        // Determine roles for user
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = ...

        // Create custom user for the principal
        User user = .....

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null /*dont store password*/, grantList);

        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    ....

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }   
}
```